# Why does negate() require an explicit cast to Predicate?

Tags: java, lambda, predicate

I have a list of names. On line 3, I had to cast the result of the lambda expression to `Predicate<String>`. The book I'm reading explains that the cast is necessary in order to help the compiler determine what the matching functional interface is.

However, I don't need such a cast on the following line because I don't call `negate()`. How does this make any difference? I understand that `negate()` here returns `Predicate<String>`, but does the preceding lambda expression not do the same?

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
//add various names here
names.removeIf(((Predicate<String>) str -> str.length() <= 5).negate()); //cast required
names.removeIf(((str -> str.length() <= 5))); //compiles without cast
```

Comment: *...the cast is necessary in order to help the compiler determine what the matching functional interface is.* answers it anyway. The reason why the next line doesn't need it is that the inference is much simpler and not followed by a method invocation on the inferred interface. I've learned using lambda functions involving generics, that it's mostly about inference in such cases and explicit declarations are much safe, such as `Predicate<String> predicate = str -> str.length() <= 5;
        names.removeIf(predicate.negate()); 
        names.removeIf(predicate);`

Comment: @Nathan Shouldn't the call to negate() have provided even more context, making the explicit cast even less necessary? The lambda expression could have referred to a Function instead of a Predicate, after all, but the subsequent call to negate() removes any room for ambiguity.

Comment: But what would the `negate()` be called upon if it's not being able to infer the type of the lambda attribute that is part of the expression and thus further unable to establish that the expression signifies a `Predicate<String>`.

Comment: I'm not saying that negate() is necessary. My last line clearly worked without it. However, I don't see how calling negate() would suddenly confuse the compiler as to the type of functional interface.

Answer (score 8):

It is not quite *just because you call `negate()`*. Take a look at this version, which is very close to yours but does compile:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = str -> str.length() <= 5;
names.removeIf(predicate.negate());
```

The difference between this and your version? It's about how lambda expressions get their types (the "target type").

What do you think this does?

```
(str -> str.length() <= 5).negate()?
```

Your current answer is that "it calls `negate()` on the `Predicate<String>` given by the expression `str -> str.length() <= 5`". Right? But that's just because this is what you meant it to do. **The compiler doesn't know that**. Why? Because it could be anything. My own answer to the above question could be "it calls `negate` on my other functional interface type... (yes, the example will be a little bizarre)

```
interface SentenceExpression {
    boolean checkGrammar();
    default SentenceExpression negate() {
        return ArtificialIntelligence.contradict(explainSentence());
    };
}
```

I could use the very same lambda expression `names.removeIf((str -> str.length() <= 5).negate());` but meaning  `str -> str.length() <= 5` to be a `SentenceExpression` rather than a `Predicate<String>`.

Explanation: `(str -> str.length() <= 5).negate()` does not make `str -> str.length() <= 5` a `Predicate<String>`. And this is why I said it could be anything, including my functional interface above.

Back to Java... This is why lambda expressions have the concept of "target type", which defines the mechanics by which a lambda expression is understood by the compiler as of a given functional interface type (i.e., how you help the compiler know that the expression is a `Predicate<String>` rather than `SentenceExpression` or anything else it could be). You may find it useful to read through [What is meant by lambda target type and target type context in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205665/what-is-meant-by-lambda-target-type-and-target-type-context-in-java/55205801#55205801) and [Java 8: Target typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196325/java-8-target-typing)

One of the contexts in which target types are inferred (if you read the answers on those posts) is the invocation context, where you pass a lambda expression as the argument for a parameter of a functional interface type, and that is what is applicable to `names.removeIf(((str -> str.length() <= 5)));`: it's just the lambda expression given as argument to a method that takes a `Predicate<String>`. This does not apply to the statement that is not compiling.

So, in other words...

`names.removeIf(str -> str.length() <= 5);` uses a lambda expression in a place where the argument type clearly defines what the type of the lambda expression is expected to be (i.e., the target type of `str -> str.length() <= 5` is clearly `Predicate<String>`).

However, `(str -> str.length() <= 5).negate()` is not a lambda expression, it's just an expression that happens to use a lambda expression. This is to say that `str -> str.length() <= 5` in this case is not in the invocation context that determines the lambda expression's target type (as in the case of your last statement). Yes, the compiler knows that `removeIf` needs a `Predicate<String>`, and it knows for sure that the entire expression passed to the method has to be a `Predicate<String>`, but it wouldn't assume that any lambda expression in the argument expression would be a `Predicate<String>` (even if you treat it as a predicate by calling `negate()` on it; it could have been anything that is compatible with the lambda expression).

That's why typing your lambda with an explicit cast (or otherwise, as in the first counter-example I gave) is needed.

Comment: names.removeIf(((str -> str.length() <= 5))); clearly compiles without issue. I still don't get how calling negate(), which returns a Predicate, suddenly causes the compiler to doubt that the whole expression refers to a Predicate.

Comment: @KMan I think you need more details on how lambda expressions are typed. I'll edit and add a link.

Comment: I have already read quite a bit about lambda expressions. Whether or not the entire expression is a lambda expression is irrelevant, isn't it? Does negate() not return Predicate<String> in my above code? I might be mistaken, but I don't think I am.

Comment: @KMan *Does negate() not return Predicate<String> in my above code?* .. No, it doesn't **until it's been called upon a `Predicate<String>`** which is what the compiler has failed to infer in the first place due to the use of `negate` itself as explained in this answer.

Comment: @KMan I've edited - I guess you need to reread the answer. In short, as Naman is saying, it boils down to understanding that `(str -> str.length() <= 5).negate()` does not make `str -> str.length() <= 5` a `Predicate<String>`, even if that's what **you** intend.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know why this has to be so confusing. This can be explained with 2 reasons, IMO.

- Lambda expressions are *poly* expressions.

I will let you figure out what this means and what the `JLS` words are around it. But in essence these are just like generics:

```
static class Me<T> {
    T t...
}
```

what is the type `T` here? Well, it depends. If you do :

```
Me<Integer> me = new Me<>(); // it's Integer
Me<String>  m2 = new Me<>(); // it's String
```

poly expressions are said that they depend on the *context* of where they are used. Lambda expressions are the same. Let's take the lambda expression in *isolation* here:

```
(String str) -> str.length() <= 5
```

when you look at it, what is this? Well it's a `Predicate<String>`? But may be A `Function<String, Boolean>`? Or may be even `MyTransformer<String, Boolean>`, where:

```
 interface MyTransformer<String, Boolean> {
     Boolean transform(String in){
         // do something here with "in"
     } 
 }
```

The choices are endless.

- In theory `.negate()` called directly *could* be an option.

From 10_000 miles above, you are correct: you are providing that `str -> str.length() <= 5` to a `removeIf` method, that only accepts a `Predicate`. There are no more `removeIf` methods, so the compiler should be able to "do the correct thing" when you supply that `(str -> str.length() <= 5).negate()`.

So how come this does not work? Let's start with your comment:

> Shouldn't the call to negate() have provided even more context, making the explicit cast even less necessary?

It seems this is where the main problem starts with, this is simply not how `javac` works. It can't take the entire `str -> str.length() <= 5).negate()`, tell itself that this is a `Predicate<String>` (since you are using it as an argument to `removeIf`) and then decompose further the part without `.negate()` and see if that is a `Predicate<String>` also. `javac` acts in reverse, it needs to know the *target* in order to be able to tell if it is legal to call `negate` or not.

Also you need to make a clear distinction between *poly expressions* and *expressions*, in general. `str -> str.length() <= 5).negate()` is an expression, `str -> str.length() <= 5` is a poly expression.

There might be languages where things are done differently and where this is possible, `javac` is simply not that type.

Answer (score 1):

In the following example

```
      names.removeIf(str -> str.length() <= 5); //compiles without cast
```

the expression returns true.  If in the following example without the cast, `true` knows nothing about the method `negate()`

On the other hand,

```
   names.removeIf(((Predicate<String>) str -> str.length() <= 5).negate()); //cast required
```

The expression is cast to `Predicate<String>` to tell the compiler where to find the method `negate`.  Then it's the method `negate()` that actually does the evaulation by the following:

```
   (s)->!test(s) where s is the string argument
```

Note that you could achieve the same result without the cast as follows:

```
    names.removeIf(str->!str.length <= 5) 
      // or
    name.removeIf(str->str.length > 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into things too deeply, the bottom line is that the lambda `str -> str.length() <= 5` is not necessarily a `Predicate<String>` as [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059372/eugene) explained.

That said, `negate()` is a member function of `Predicate<T>` and the compiler isn't able to use the call to `negate()` to help with inferring the type that the lambda should be interpreted as.  Even if it tried there might be issues because if multiple possible classes had `negate()` functions it wouldn't know which to choose.

Imagine that you're the compiler.

- You see `str -> str.length() <= 5`.  You know that it is lambda that takes a String and returns a boolean but don't know specifically which type it represents.
- You next see the member reference `.negate()` but because you don't know the type of the expression to the left of the "." you need to report an error since you can't use the call to negate to help infer the type.

Had negate been implemented as a static function then things would work.  For example:

```
public class PredicateUtils {
    public static <T> Predicate<T> negate(Predicate<T> p) {
        return p.negate();
}
```

would enable you to write

```
names.removeIf(PredicateUtils.negate(str -> str.length() <= 5)); //compiles without cast
```

Because the choice of negate function is unambiguous the compiler knows that it needs to interpret `str -> str.length() <= 5` as a `Predicate<T>` and can coerce the type properly.

I hope that this helps.